# CSV Export for Grouped Columns in datatable in PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

Does anybody has a working example for datatable CSV Export for grouped headers? I was looking for a post processor, but I didn't find it for CSV data exporter.

Here is the grouped example from Primefaces demo - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/group.xhtml

I need to have my csv export as below:

```
Manufacturer, Last Year, This Year, Last Year, This Year
Apple, 52%, 60%, $76,981.00, $48,637.00
Samsung, 77%, 39%, $46,739.00, $72,752.00
```